# How can I select all rows with sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pylons

I am trying to get all rows from a table.

In controller I have:

```python
meta.Session.query(User).all()
```

The result is `[, ]`, but I have 2 rows in this table.

I use this model for the table:

```python
import hashlib
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import orm

from allsun.model import meta

t_user =  sa.Table("users",meta.metadata,autoload=True)

class Duplicat(Exception):
    pass
class LoginExistsException(Exception):
    pass
class EmailExistsException(Exception):
    pass
```

And next, in the same file:

```python
class User(object):
    def loginExists(self):
        try:
            meta.Session
                .query(User)
                .filter(User.login==self.login)
                .one()
        except orm.exc.NoResultFound:
            pass
        else:
            raise LoginExistsException()

    def emailExists(self):
        try:
            meta
                .Session
                .query(User)
                .filter(User.email==self.email)
                .one()
        except orm.exc.NoResultFound:
            pass
        else:
            raise EmailExistsException()


    def save(self):
        meta.Session.begin()
        meta.Session.save(self)
        try:
            meta.Session.commit()
        except sa.exc.IntegrityError:
            raise Duplicat()

orm.mapper(User, t_user)
```

Comment: There is not enough information to reproduce your problem. What is `[, ]`? It's not valid python expression, but rather looks like you are printing a list of two items `[<User instance at ...>, <User instance at ...>]` on HTML without properly escaping it.

Comment: To solve that you can `from flask import Markup` and then `return Markup("%r") % User.query.all()`.

Answer (score 129):

You can easily import your model and run this:

```
from models import User

# User is the name of table that has a column name
users = User.query.all()

for user in users:
    print user.name
```

Comment: What's the difference between using this code and using ´session.query(SomeTable).all()´?

Comment: i believe 'User.query.all()' uses core. Where ´session.query(SomeTable).all()´ is ORM

Comment: NOTE: This syntax, as far as I can see from the docs, is only available using Flask-SQLAlchemy, not SQLAlchemy directly, which uses `select(User)` function

Comment: When you go ahead and do `print(user)` . It prints it in the format `<TableName primary_key>`. I thought this might help if you are wondering. It access a certain column entry per row, you can do `print(user.column_name)`. Have a Nice One!

Answer (score 12):

I use the following snippet to view all the rows in a table. Use a query to find all the rows. The returned objects are the class instances. They can be used to view/edit the values as required:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Sequence
from sqlalchemy import String, Integer, Float, Boolean, Column
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()

class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'MyTable'
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('user_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    some_col = Column(String(500))

    def __init__(self, some_col):
        self.some_col = some_col

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///sqllight.db', echo=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

for class_instance in session.query(MyTable).all():
    print(vars(class_instance))

session.close()
```